# What is the relationship between Multicollinearity and Standard error?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Can somebody give a clear explanation for the relationship between Multicollinearity and Standard error? I heard if multicollinearity exists, then the standard error goes up, but I don't understand this sentence. How does multicollinearity make the standard error go up?

Answer (score 1):

Multicollinearity does not bias regression results; it just produces large standard deviations for the parameters related to the independent variables.

Comment: Then why people say the standard error goes up when there is multicollinearity? Can you be more specific for me to understand better?

Comment: You must have a look to the matrix formulation of multilinear regression and to the manner the standard deviations are computed for the parameters. If the case of collinearity, the matrix is very poorly conditioned.

Comment: Many thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments and I will go for some more research on it.